# Using CSS Grid with Bootstrap 4 and my layout is behaving strangely. If I don't have <br> tags between every element, everything is placed in rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

If I do things like place my image in a div or remove the 
 tags, the layout of everything jumps to really strange positions. This also makes it hard to position anything. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong with the Grid or what is happening.

Here's a link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/amandathedev/pen/zyEyze

If you remove the 
 tags in this section, you'll see what I mean:

```
    <br>
    <h2 id="heading">
      A <strong>modern</strong> approach to beautiful writing.
    </h2>
    <br>
      <img class="photo mx-auto" src="https://bydawnnicole.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/image-3-1024x765.jpeg" alt="Hello summer written in modern calligraphy with blended watercolors">
    <br>
```

Thank you!

Comment: "If you remove the tags in this section" <- which, the break tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
display: grid;
```

For this reason, elements inside are laid out in a grid (inspect and hover the div to see the highlighted grid areas).
By putting a break tag you merely push it down within the same grid item, by leaving the break tag out you treat the following content as the content of the next grid box.

See the grid here:
[image]

**To keep everything in one grid box, use a container around the content within the grid box.**

I'd also recommend looking into flex, if this could be a better option.

If I'm misunderstanding your question please do let me know!

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thank you so much! I know I could probably use flexbox instead, but I am only doing this project so I can practice Grid. :) Thank you!

Comment: awesome, happy to help.
If it worked, mark it as correct and get me some points :)